# Intel XDK - How to Create Service ?

Tags: web-services, intel-xdk

I'm trying to get the data returned from:

[www.w3schools.com/webservices/tempconvert.asmx?op=CelsiusToFahrenheit](http://www.w3schools.com/webservices/tempconvert.asmx?op=CelsiusToFahrenheit)

by using *Intel XDK*, but I can't figure out how to do it...

When I push "*create new service*" - button, it creates 2 files one **.js** and the otherone **.json**.

I've tried to analyze the code, but I can't get it to work.

Also there is no good tutorials on the Internet...

Plz show/help me how to use the Service(tempconvert -> CelsiusToFahrenheit) in **Intel XDK**.

Answer (score 0):

Let me suggest that you see the video 
https://software.intel.com/en-us/html5/videos/using-services-datafeed-in-brackets 
and read this article with links 
https://software.intel.com/en-us/html5/article/using-the-services-tab

Comment: Also see these links: https://software.intel.com/en-us/html5/videos/integrating-a-new-service and https://software.intel.com/en-us/html5/article/using-the-services-tab#service_createown